# How can I re-render a component when I submit a form in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I have three components on the main page.(`PostDetail,CreateComment,Comments`). I have a Firebase `posts` collection.The `posts` collection has a field called `comments`. In the `CreateComment` component, I have a submit button that adds a comment to the comments field. The problem is that after I add a new comment, it won't be displayed immediately. The function works, but to see the new comment, I have to go back and open the post again. I want to re-render the `Comment` component in the `Comments` when a new comment is added.

I have a state called `postDetail` in ContextAPI. It has all the information about that specific post. I set the `postDetail` state from postList in another component. I thought to use useEffect with the `postDetail` state so that whenever a comment added that state, it would be changed, but it didn't work.

This is main page

```
 <div>
      <PostDetail />
      <CreateComment />
      <Comments />
 </div>
```

Submit function that adds comment in the CreateComment component

```
  const createComment = async (author, authorId, comment) => {
    const docRef = doc(db, "posts", id);
    await updateDoc(docRef, {
      comments: arrayUnion({ author, authorId, comment }),
    });
  };
```

Comments:

```
 <div>
      <Comment />
 </div>
```

Comment :

```
 const Comment = () => {
  const { isDark, postDetail } = useContext(AppContext);

  return (
    <>
      {postDetail?.comments.map((post) => (
        <div>
          <div>
            <Avatar/>

            <div>
              <p>{post.author} </p>
              <p>5 min ago</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <p> {post.comment}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: can you provide the entier `comment` component ? this is not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add this in `createComment` function and it worked

```
 setPostDetail({
      ...postDetail,
      comments: [...postDetail.comments, { author, authorId, comment }],
    });
```

New function :

```
const createComment = async (author, authorId, comment) => {
    const docRef = doc(db, "posts", id);
    await updateDoc(docRef, {
      comments: arrayUnion({ author, authorId, comment }),
    });
    setPostDetail({
      ...postDetail,
      comments: [...postDetail.comments, { author, authorId, comment }],
    });
  };
```